# Large amount of Deferred Objects leads to call stack exceedance

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a large amount of asynchronous calls that I need to synchronize. Therefore I wanted to use jquerys deferred objects, but unfortunately a "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" is thrown in Chrome 25 as well as in IE 9 when I call the "then"-function if there are more than about 62000 promises.

```
var promises= []
for(var i=0; i < 63000;++i) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    promises.push(def.promise());           
    def.resolve();
}

var regEntries = $.when.apply(null, promises);
regEntries.then(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

You can also try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/f8LPG/

Do you have an idea why this happens and how I can use more deferred objects?

Comment: Perform a top-to-bottom review of your code.

Comment: If you have 62000 simultaneous promises, you should reconsider the entire approach, as you're doing something seriously wrong.

Comment: I'm using the new DragAndDropEntries and I need to traverse through a directory with sometimes up to 100000 files in subdirectories to get their sizes. Therefore I have to call the FileEntrys async function "file()" (http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/#the-fileentry-interface). The deferred objects are resolved very quickly, but I have many of them :/

Comment: You need to find a way to traverse the directory without keeping explicit references to all the promises. That way, Garbage Collection will stand a chance of keeping things under control.